# Click to move animation not working

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animator

The bases of my game is a simple 2D top down click to move game I. I created a walk blend tree and a idle blend tree. The both blend tree has 6 directional movement. I watch this tutorial on Top-down 8 directions movement. (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7URRg8J6mz8). Basically I change the script around so that it could match with my click to move script, but it not 100% perfect. My idle state is not working properly or neither is my Y-axis, to be more speific, when I click long the Y-axis (let's say i'm going up(+)) it's not really playing the right animation in the animator. (Now let's say I went down) It would play the right animation but (when finished with movement) it would continue playing the animation. My parameters are also not working properly, SpeedY and LastMoveY aren't stable (if i'm making any sense). Can someone help me fix this? Here's my game preview uploaded in google drive if anyone doesn't understand what I mean! http://html.editey.com/file/0B6cfYGCOex7BVC1Ja3Q3N3d3NWc#

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class move : MonoBehaviour {

private Animator anim;
public float speed = 15f;
public move playerMovementRef;
private Vector3 target;
private Vector3 playerObject;


void Start () {
    target = transform.position;
    anim = GetComponent<Animator> ();
}

void Update () {
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) {
        target = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
        target.z = transform.position.z;
    }
    transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, target, speed * Time.deltaTime);
    float inputX = Input.GetAxis ("Mouse X");
    float inputY = Input.GetAxis ("Mouse Y");

    if (Input.touchCount > 0)
    {
        inputX = Input.touches[0].deltaPosition.x;
        inputY = Input.touches[0].deltaPosition.y;
    }

    anim.SetFloat ("SpeedX", inputX);
    anim.SetFloat ("SpeedY", inputY);

}

void FixedUpdate () {

    float LastInputX = Input.GetAxis ("Mouse X");
    float LastInputY = Input.GetAxis ("Mouse Y");

    if (Input.touchCount > 0)
    {
        LastInputX = Input.touches[0].deltaPosition.x;
        LastInputY = Input.touches[0].deltaPosition.y;
    }

    if (LastInputX != 0 || LastInputY != 0) {
        anim.SetBool ("walking", true);
        if (LastInputX > 0) {
            anim.SetFloat ("LastMoveX", 1f);
        } else if (LastInputX < 0) {
            anim.SetFloat ("LastMoveX", -1f);
        } else {
            anim.SetBool ("walking", false);
        }
        if (LastInputY > 0) {
            anim.SetFloat ("LastMoveY", 1f);
        } else if (LastInputY < 0) {
            anim.SetFloat ("LastMoveY", -1f);
        } else {
            anim.SetFloat ("LastMoveY", 0f);
        }

    } else {
        anim.SetBool ("walking", false);
    }
}
```

Comment: can you put your "Inspector" window?

Comment: huh...........? what do you mean by "can you put your "Inspector" window?" Do you mean: can I put my animation in my Inspector window? or do I control my animation from the inspector window? Well either way I don't use the inspector window for animation because I'm not using the animation component, I'm using the animator window and blend trees. Thank you for replying back though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not use **Input** values inside FixedUpdate. You should store it in a variable inside Update and then check it inside FixedUpdate.

You should also add some depth to the mouse position according to your camera.

wrong:

```
void FixedUpdate () {
       if (Input.touchCount > 0)
       {
           ...
       }
}
```

correct:

```
    void Update () {
           ...
           if (Input.touchCount > 0)
           {
                touched = true;
           }
    }

    void FixedUpdate () {
           if (touched)
           {
                ...
           }
    }
```

sample:

```
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        Vector3 mousePosition = Input.mousePosition;
        mousePosition.z = 10; // distance from the camera
        target = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(mousePosition);
        target.z = transform.position.z;
    }

    if (Input.touchCount > 0)
    {
        target.x = Input.touches[0].deltaPosition.x;
        target.y = Input.touches[0].deltaPosition.y;
    }

    transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, target, speed * Time.deltaTime);
}

void FixedUpdate()
{
    float LastInputX = transform.position.x - target.x;
    float LastInputY = transform.position.y - target.y;

    if (LastInputX != 0 || LastInputY != 0)
    {
        anim.SetBool("walking", true);
        if (LastInputX > 0)
        {
            anim.SetFloat("LastMoveX", 1f);
        }
        else if (LastInputX < 0)
        {
            anim.SetFloat("LastMoveX", -1f);
        }
        else {
            anim.SetBool("walking", false);
        }
        if (LastInputY > 0)
        {
            anim.SetFloat("LastMoveY", 1f);
        }
        else if (LastInputY < 0)
        {
            anim.SetFloat("LastMoveY", -1f);
        }
        else {
            anim.SetFloat("LastMoveY", 0f);
        }

    }
    else {
        anim.SetBool("walking", false);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for replying back (sorry for the delay). I have tried out what you suggested and it worked a lot. Thank you, my animation doesn't play by mouse movement, but it doesn't play when I click to a position either! What could I do, again sorry for replaying back so late!!! Thank you again.

Comment: Thank you it worked perfectly. I change it a bit so that my player would move in all 4 directions. My only problem now is that my LastMoveX and LastMoveY isn't functioning well. What I mean is that When I click to the right during the movement my player would flip to the left for a bit the flip back to the right, then once it gets to it's last position it would face left instead of right. It also does the same thing but when I click to the left. Another problem I have is moving along the Y axis. When I click below my player my animation doesn't stop, not until I click above to make it stop.

Comment: I added this into my void update: var movementDirection = (target - transform.position).normalized; anim.SetFloat("SpeedX", movementDirection.x);
  anim.SetFloat("SpeedY", movementDirection.y);

Comment: void FixedUpdate () {

float LastInputX = transform.position.x - target.x;
float LastInputY = transform.position.y - target.y;

if (LastInputX != 0 || LastInputY != 0) {
anim.SetBool ("walking", true);
if (LastInputX > 0) {
anim.SetFloat ("LastMoveX", 1f);
} else if (LastInputX < 0) {
anim.SetFloat ("LastMoveX", -1f);
} else {
anim.SetBool ("walking", false);
}
if (LastInputY > 0) {
anim.SetFloat ("LastMoveY", 1f);
} else if (LastInputY < 0) {
anim.SetFloat ("LastMoveY", -1f);
} else {
anim.SetFloat ("LastMoveY", 0f);
   }
} else {
anim.SetBool ("walking", false);
  }
}